# jQuery : Is there any way to trigger action of selector of select using another button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to actually show the options when i write something in textbox. when i write any thing in a textbox then all the matching options should shows up.

my code looks like

```js
$('#location_from_input').keyup(function() {
  var txt = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  $('#location_from>option').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    textL = text.toLowerCase();
    (textL.indexOf(txt) == 0) ? window.alert(text): $(this).hide();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Going From" id="location_from_input" />
  <select name="location_from" class="full-width" id="location_from" onchange="document.getElementById('location_from_input').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">
    <option value="location_1">Location 1</option>
    <option value="location_2">Location 2</option>
    <option value="location_3">Location 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into things like jQuery UI Autocomplete or select2.

Comment: Also, don't write event handlers into your HTML (`onchange="..."`), especially not when you have jQuery.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot open a `<select>` programmatically. Only the user can do this.

The functionality you want is in a different element type `datalist`, and it doesn't even require Javascript:

```html
<label for="myBrowser">Pick your browser:</label>
<input list="browsers" id="myBrowser" name="myBrowser" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```